# what is the 90/90 shown in Keras output data while training the model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

`90/90 - 0s - loss: 0.0098 - accuracy: 0.0011` This is my output while training my model .
what is that 90/90 ? if it is the number of samples passed , My data set has 1001 rows and 9 columns ! so shouldn't the output be 1001/1001 ?
My code is shown below :

```
model = Sequential([
Dense(9,input_shape=(9,),activation='relu'),
Dense(25,activation='relu'),
Dense(18,activation='relu'),
Dense(1,activation='sigmoid')
])
model.compile(
optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.001),
loss='mean_squared_error',
metrics=['accuracy']
)
model.fit(
scaled_train_data,
label_set,
validation_split=0.1,
batch_size=10,
epochs=2000,
shuffle=True,
verbose=2
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a validation split of 0.1, so training has 900 samples. Thus, with `batch_size=10`, 90 batches are there. That is the reason of 90/90.